# Create a String with a single char with dynamic range

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

i am making a report using JasperReports, which is connecting to a database table that has an integer field "LEVEL".
This level will store some numbers... 1, 2, 3, and going on.
In the report, i want to create a string with this numbers of underlines, which means if the level is 4 the generated string would be "*_*_".
I know i can do it with in java something like this:

```
int i = 3;
char[] vect = new char[i];
Arrays.fill(vect, '_');
System.out.println(vect);
```

But in JasperReports i can not call commands, i could if the Arrays.fill would return the array itself instead of void.
Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a for loop to append a string.
Im not sure if I know exactly what you mean but maybe something like this

```
int i = 3;
String s;
for(int k = 0; k < i; i++){
    s = s + "_";
}
System.out.print(s);
```

not tested, but looks ok

Comment: The problem is that in JasperReports, you can not run a batch of commands in the text field expressions, you can execute only a single command that returns an object of the specified class of the text field.

Answer (score 0):

If number of LEVEL is not much higher number, then you could conditionally write it with if else as shown below:

```
$F{level}.equals("1")?"_":
              $F{level}.equals("2")?"__":
                       $F{level}.equals("3")?"___":____  <---- last one is 4
```

It goes on...

It won't be a good solution but you can't have another option in jasper for such operation. :)

Comment: the number goes from 0 to infinite, so it's impossible to do it.

Comment: oh... then it won't be possible with jasper at all.